# Pending intent doesn't fire because of another intent in onPause

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-pendingintent, onpause

Consider the following scenario:

1. A notification is created with a pending intent (with some extras) to open some activity (let's say `ActivityA`) inside the app WHILE the app is running
2. The Activity in focus (`ActivityFocus`) at the time when the notification comes in overrides the `onPause()` method to open ANOTHER activity

   `@Override
   public void onPause() {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
   }`
3. The user taps on the notification - now according to the `onPause()` documentation, the intent inside `ActivityFocus` will fire BEFORE the intent inside the `PendingIntent`

> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.
>   - From Android Documentation

4. Finally, the app launches `ActivityB` and completely ignores the `PendingIntent`

How can I fix this (without removing the `onPause()`) so that either:

- The `PendingIntent` will fire AFTER `onPause()` execution is finished
- The intent inside `onPause()` is somehow overridden by the intent inside the `PendingIntent`

Hopefully my question makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, your architecture is a bit strange. Why do you launch another `Activity` in `onPause()`? That will cause all kinds of strange behaviour.

Comment: @DavidWasser Its because of security reasons (we logout the app when `onPause()` fires). In either case, it's legacy code so changing it is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the `PendingIntent` from the `Notification` should still get launched. Can you post the code you use to create the `Notification` and also post the relevant parts of the manifest (The Activity being started by the Notification and `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`